# Refile accepts_attachments_for issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, refile

I'm using Refile with a rails 4 app.

I'm getting the error: `undefined method`accepts_attachments_for'`

I'm trying to do multiple image upload, and have two models: books and blobs.

My books.rb:

```
has_many :blobs, dependent: :destroy
accepts_attachments_for :blobs
```

My blobs.rb:

```
belongs_to :book
attachment :file
```

If I check rake routes, it shows that refile is mounted, so what is the issue?

Comment: Could you post the complete error log?

Comment: @Pavan, here: `NoMethodError (undefined method accepts_attachments_for for #<Class:0x007ff2a46a5b50>):
  app/models/book.rb:6:in <class:Book>
  app/models/book.rb:1:in <top (required)>
  app/controllers/books_controller.rb:17:in new`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you're looking to use is discussed here: https://github.com/refile/refile/issues/6 and it doesn't seem to be released yet. If you want to use it, you'll need to use the master branch. You can try using the master branch by changing your Gemfile:

```rb
gem 'refile', require: "refile/rails", git: 'https://github.com/refile/refile.git', branch: 'master'
```